# Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined with the ERROR on *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to declare an index in *ngFor but I am getting a type error and it is saying

```
<div class='text' *ngFor='let item of blogs; let i = index | async | filter : 'feat' : true'>
```

If I take out `let i = index` it works fine, but I want to use the index, so I can apply css classes to the elements. Looking at documentation, this is how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for contributing, your question could however benefit from some code examples. It also helps if you can share what you have already tried before reaching out to the community. You are trying to pass a parameter to your toUpperCase pipe which is undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It pipe should come before the index

```
<div class='text' *ngFor='let item of blogs | async | filter : 'feat' : true'; let i = index >
```